# Replace unicode by its value in a dataframe

Tags: r, unicode, shiny

I tried to replace the unicode "U+00F3" from a data frame with the sapply function but nothing happened. The unicode part I want to replace is a chr type.

Here the function :

```
tableExcel$Team <- sapply(tableExcel$Team, gsub, pattern = "<U+00F3>", replacement= "o")
```

EDIT :

Thanks to the answer of Cath below, I added before the + : \\

```
tableExcel$Team <- sapply(tableExcel$Team, gsub, pattern = "<U\\+00F3>", replacement= "o")
```

But it didn't work.

I also tried to provide an exemple of my dataset but the problem is that it works on it and not on mine :

```
tableExcel <- data.frame("Team" = c("A", "B", "C", "Reducci<U+00F3>n"), "Point" = c(2, 30, 40, 30))
tableExcel$Team <- as.character(tableExcel$Team)
```

To provide more information, here the importation of my excel file:

```
tableExcel <- as.data.frame(read_excel("Dataset LOS.xls", sheet = "Liga Squads"))
```

The structure of my data :

```
structure(list(Team = c("CHURN", "CHURN", "RESIDENCIAL NPTB", "RESIDENCIAL NPTB", "AUDIENCIAS TV", "AUDIENCIAS TV"), Points = c("P. Asig", "P. entr", "P. Asig", "P. entr", "P. Asig", "P. entr"), 2019-S01 = c(0, 0, 50, 0, NA, NA), 2019-S02 = c(0, 0, 10, 10, NA, NA), 2019-S03 = c(93, 88, 46, 19, NA, NA), 2019-S04 = c(56, 48, 0, 0, 13, 13), 2019-S05 = c(NA, NA, 80.5, 49.5, 42, 28.5), 2019-S06 = c(NA, NA, 66, 48, 55, 39.5), 2019-S07 = c(131, 112, 103, 63, 40.5, 38)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you need to add `fixed=TRUE` for `gsub` or escape special characters (`"<U\\+00F3>"` instead of `"<U+00F3>"`) as `+` means *"one or more times"* in regex and not jsut "+", see `?regex`

Comment: I tried like that but it didn't work : ```tableExcel$Team <- gsub("<U\\+00F3>", "o", tableExcel$Team,fixed = TRUE)```

Comment: either escape OR put `fixed=TRUE`: your line is searching for "<U\\+00F3>" as is

Comment: It didn't work. Maybe it is because of the <> ?

Comment: then we will need a little more information... because `gsub("<U\\+00F3>", "o", "aaa<U+00F3>")` gives `[1] "aaao"` as expected. (< and > do not need to be escaped)

Comment: Ok it works for me as well but when I tried in the data frame nothing happen : ```tableExcel <- as.data.frame(read_excel("Dataset LOS.xls", sheet = "Liga Squads"))```

Comment: As I haven't your data and thus cannot know how they look like, it is quite difficult for me to just guess... Please see how to make a [mcve]

Comment: I edited my question with a minimal exemple

Comment: `gsub("<U\\+00F3>", "o", tableExcel$Team)`: `[1] "A"         "B"         "C"         "Reduccion"`...

Comment: Oups I forget to put the \\. Now i don't understand becquse it works here but not in my real code ... and i didn't forget anything

Comment: I reopen your question as the problem seems to not be only the escaping of "+" sign (though it was the orginal question). However, like it is right now, we cannot reproduce the error, hence not help you

Comment: As the problem you mentioned is not reproducible from the example you shared, it is difficult to help you. Please try to add `dput(head(tableExcel))` data from your actual data.

Comment: structure(list(Team = c("CHURN", "CHURN", "RESIDENCIAL NPTB", 
"RESIDENCIAL NPTB", "AUDIENCIAS TV", "AUDIENCIAS TV"), Points = c("P. Asig", 
"P. entr", "P. Asig", "P. entr", "P. Asig", "P. entr"), `2019-S01` = c(0, 
0, 50, 0, NA, NA), `2019-S02` = c(0, 0, 10, 10, NA, NA), `2019-S03` = c(93, 
88, 46, 19, NA, NA), `2019-S04` = c(56, 48, 0, 0, 13, 13), `2019-S05` = c(NA, 
NA, 80.5, 49.5, 42, 28.5), `2019-S06` = c(NA, NA, 66, 48, 55, 
39.5), `2019-S07` = c(131, 112, 103, 63, 40.5, 38)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: in your data.frame whose structure you gave in the comment above (and which should be in the main Q), there is no unicode bit...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your data where it can be formatted and is more noticeable instead of in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate the issue with `gsub`. The following works as expected:

```r
tableExcel$Team <- gsub("<U\\+00F3>", "o", tableExcel$Team)

#### OUTPUT ####

              Team  Points 2019-S01 2019-S02 2019-S03 2019-S04 2019-S05 2019-S06 2019-S07
1 Reducci<U+00F1>n P. Asig        0        0       93       56       NA       NA    131.0
2            CHURN P. entr        0        0       88       48       NA       NA    112.0
4 Reducci<U+00F2>n P. Asig       50       10       46        0     80.5     66.0    103.0
5 RESIDENCIAL NPTB P. entr        0       10       19        0     49.5     48.0     63.0
7    AUDIENCIAS TV P. Asig       NA       NA       NA       13     42.0     55.0     40.5
8             <NA> P. entr       NA       NA       NA       13     28.5     39.5     38.0
9        Reduccion P. entr       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

However, replacement using regular expressions might not be the most efficient way convert the unicode characters, as this would require multiple calls to `gsub`. Instead, you might want to give stringi's `stri_unescape_unicode()` a try:

```r
# install.packages("stringi") # Use if not yet installed.
library(stringi)

tableExcel$Team <- stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(.*)>", "\\\\u\\1", tableExcel$Team))

#### OUTPUT ####

              Team  Points 2019-S01 2019-S02 2019-S03 2019-S04 2019-S05 2019-S06 2019-S07
1        Reducciñn P. Asig        0        0       93       56       NA       NA    131.0
2            CHURN P. entr        0        0       88       48       NA       NA    112.0
4        Reducciòn P. Asig       50       10       46        0     80.5     66.0    103.0
5 RESIDENCIAL NPTB P. entr        0       10       19        0     49.5     48.0     63.0
7    AUDIENCIAS TV P. Asig       NA       NA       NA       13     42.0     55.0     40.5
8             <NA> P. entr       NA       NA       NA       13     28.5     39.5     38.0
9        Reducción P. entr       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

The format `<U+0000>` is first converted to `\\u0000` using `gsub` and then unescaped. As you can see, it takes care of multiple unicode characters in one go, which makes things much simpler.

#### Data:

```r
tableExcel <- structure(list(Team = c("Reducci<U+00F1>n", "CHURN", "Reducci<U+00F2>n", 
"RESIDENCIAL NPTB", "AUDIENCIAS TV", NA, "Reducci<U+00F3>n"), 
    Points = c("P. Asig", "P. entr", "P. Asig", "P. entr", "P. Asig", 
    "P. entr", "P. entr"), `2019-S01` = c(0, 0, 50, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA), `2019-S02` = c(0, 0, 10, 10, NA, NA, NA), `2019-S03` = c(93, 
    88, 46, 19, NA, NA, NA), `2019-S04` = c(56, 48, 0, 0, 13, 
    13, NA), `2019-S05` = c(NA, NA, 80.5, 49.5, 42, 28.5, NA), 
    `2019-S06` = c(NA, NA, 66, 48, 55, 39.5, NA), `2019-S07` = c(131, 
    112, 103, 63, 40.5, 38, NA)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I took your code but it didn't do anything on my dataset..

Comment: Ok It seems R cloud is not working very well, it's the second time that it didn't take in count what I'm doing. Anyway, now it works thanks !